# Can't learn parameters of tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag via optimization

Tags: tensorflow

Working example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

## construct data
np.random.seed(723888)
N,P = 50,3 # number and dimensionality of observations
Xbase = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros((P,)), cov=np.eye(P), size=N)

## construct model
X      = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, P), name='X')
mu     = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.1, size=(P,)), dtype=tf.float32, name='mu')
xDist  = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=tf.ones(shape=(P,), dtype=tf.float32), name='xDist')
xProbs = xDist.prob(X, name='xProbs')

## prepare optimizer
eta       = 1e-3 # learning rate
loss      = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(xProbs), name='loss')
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=eta).minimize(loss)

## launch session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: Xbase})
```

I want to do optimization over the parameters of a multivariate gaussian distribution in tensorflow, as in my above example. I can successfully run commands like `sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: Xbase})`, so I have implemented the distribution correctly. When I try to run the optimization op, I get an odd error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError: -1 is not between 0 and 3
     [[Node: gradients_1/xDist_7/xProbs/Prod_grad/InvertPermutation = InvertPermutation[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](gradients_1/xDist_7/xProbs/Prod_grad/concat)]]

Caused by op 'gradients_1/xDist_7/xProbs/Prod_grad/InvertPermutation'
```

That I do not understand.

I get the same error message if I use `tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance` instead of `tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag`. I do not get the error if `scale_diag` and not `loc` is the variable being optimized over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still looking into why this is failing, but for a short-term fix, does making the following change work?

```
xLogProbs = xDist.log_prob(X, name='xLogProbs')
loss      = -tf.reduce_mean(xLogProbs, name='loss')
```

Note: this is actually preferable to `tf.log(xProbs)` because it is never less numerically precise--and sometimes substantially more precise. (This is true of all tf.Distributions.)

Comment: Using `.log_prob` works. Thanks; I have not used `tf.Distributions` much.

Comment: I've tracked down the issue. It appears that the release version of TF doesn't correctly handle negative indexes for `reduce_prod`. The issue has been fixed in master. In any case, `log_prob` is preferred.  Also note: for reasons too complicated here, its better to use `tf.get_variable` rather than `tf.Variable`. Best of luck!